# How to convert a timestamp in string format to datetime data type within a package?

Tags: ssis

Could someone guide me on how to convert `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM` that comes from a flat file source as a string to a datetime to a ole db destination using the derived column.

This is my flow.

```
Flatfile -> Data Coversion -> Derived Column
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are couple of ways to achieve this. You can use the `Derived Column transformation` to convert the value **or** you can declare the flat file column on the Flat File Connection as column of data type **`database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]`**. Steps **1** - **8** describes the first option and step **9** describes the second option.

**Step-by-step process:**

1. This example uses the flat file named `Source.txt` shown in screenshot #**1**.
2. `Flat File Connection` is configured as shown in screenshots #**2** and #**3**.
3. `Data Flow Task` is configured as shown in Screenshot #**4**.
4. Flat File Source is configured as shown in Screenshot #**5**.
5. `Derived Transformation` task is configured as shown in screenshot #**6** using the type cast **DT_DBTIMESTAMP** to convert the string value to date time value.
6. `OLE DB Destination` is configured as shown in screenshot #**7**.
7. Screenshot #**8** displays the sample package execution.
8. Screenshot #**9** displays the data in the SQL table after the package execution.
9. another easier way to do this to declare the column that contains the date time value as data type **`database timestamp [DT_DBTIMESTAMP]`** as shown in screenshot #**10**. This way you don't need a `Derived Column Transformation` and the `Data Flow Task` will be as shown in screenshot #**11**. You can directly map the `Flat File` columns to the `OLE DB destination` columns.

Hope that helps.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

**Screenshot #7:**

[image: 7]

**Screenshot #8:**

[image: 8]

**Screenshot #9:**

[image: 9]

**Screenshot #10:**

[image: 10]

**Screenshot #11:**

[image: 11]

Comment: Sir, in my csv the string is like this : 2014-02-24T23:17:59Z
then I try use dt_date, database timestamp, database timestamp with precision, and database timestamp with timezone nothing works.. Please give me suggestion..